# Setting the text of a UILabel with a constant

Tags: swift, uilabel, constants

I am a total newby to xCode and Swift so please excuse me if this question is silly.
I am trying to update 2 UILabels and a UIImageView by using the sender.currentTitle of the button pressed.

If a user presses the 'Honduras' button then I want to populate the 2 UILabel with it's corresponding information and the UIImageView with its corresponding image file.
I have the first UILabel working and the UIImageView working but cannot find a way to populate the 2nd UILabel with its corresponding text (which is stored in a constant).

UILabel 1 is called `@IBOutlet weak var countryLabel: UILabel!`

UILabel 2 is called `@IBOutlet weak var peopleLabel: UILabel!`

UImageView is called `@IBOutlet weak var peopleUIImageView: UIImageView!`

The information/file name I want to pass into these 3 are called:

"Honduras"

```
let peopleHondurasText = "The Lenca"
```

"peopleHonduras.png"

I have the UILabel 1 working like this:

```
countryLabel.text = sender.currentTitle
```

I have the image working by calling this func:

```
func findCountryImages() {
peopleUIImageView.image = UIImage(named: "people\(countryLabel.text! .filter { !" ".contains($0) }).png")
}
```

and I am trying to call the constant "peopleHondurasText" like I did the UIImage but it isn't working.
Here is my very amateur code:

```
peopleLabel.text = "people\(countryLabel.text! .filter { !" ".contains($0) })Text"
```

Where this:

```
"people\(countryLabel.text! .filter { !" ".contains($0) })Text"
```

Should be equal to the constant named:

```
peopleHondurasText
```

I want to be able to do this so if a user clicks on any country button it will populate those 2 UILabels and UIImageViews with that countries text and images.

I know I must be doing something fundamentally incorrect or maybe going about this complete in the wrong but if anyone could let me know either how to pass the constant name into the UILable
or tell me that you cannot do this and I should try something different, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How come you don't just do:

peopleLabel.text = peopleHondurasText

Comment: Hi, thank you. I need it to work for all countries not just Honduras. So while that would be good for Honduras it wouldn't work for the other 200 countries.